# What is type of native constructor which throws exception in Frege?

Tags: frege

I'm trying to figure out native interface. I'm trying to send some message using `UDP`. Here what I have:

```
module UDPTest where    

data StringAsBytes = native java.lang.String where
  native getBytes :: String -> ST s (Mutable s (JArray Byte))    

data InetSocketAddress = native java.net.InetSocketAddress where
  native new :: String -> Int -> ST s (Mutable s InetSocketAddress)

data DatagramPacket = native java.net.DatagramPacket where
  native new :: Mutable s (JArray Byte)  -> Int -> Mutable s InetSocketAddress ->  ST s (Mutable s DatagramPacket)    

data DatagramSocket = native java.net.DatagramSocket where
  native new :: () -> IOMutable DatagramSocket throws SocketException
  native send ::  Mutable RealWorld DatagramSocket -> MutableIO DatagramPacket -> IO () throws IOException
  native close :: MutableIO DatagramSocket -> IO ()    

data SocketException = native java.net.SocketException
derive Exceptional SocketException   

main _ = do
  messageStr = "hello world;\n"
  messageAsBytes <- StringAsBytes.getBytes messageStr
  address <- InetSocketAddress.new "localhost" 3003
  messageLen <- messageAsBytes.getLength
  packet <- DatagramPacket.new messageAsBytes messageLen address
  socket <- DatagramSocket.new ()
  socket.send packet
  socket.close
```

This code accidentally runs but it makes me wonder few things. Firstly, what should be a type of `DatagramSocket.new` to reflect the fact of throwing exception? I had tried to pack it into `Maybe` but it ended up in a total mess. Is there any way to do it? For now, I have no idea how to handle exceptions in `main` and [this](https://mmhelloworld.github.io/blog/2013/07/10/frege-hello-java/) doesn't address it fully or maybe I'm missing something.
Secondly,  Why I was forced by compiler to change `InetSocketAddress` from `pure` to impure, to use it in `DatagramSocket.new`? I was also forced to use mutable version of `JArray` wherever it was needed in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning exceptions: There are 2 ways of managing exceptions.

The first is by wrapping the return type in an `Either`. This will give you the value you want in `Right` and the exception in `Left` when it occures.
To handle the exception, you generally use pattern matching or the `either` function. Unfortunately, in IO code (like in your case) this would lead to code like

```
do
   r1 <- Socket.new ...
   case r1 of
      Left -> -- handle exception
      Right x -> do
           r2 -> x.send ....
           case r2 of
              ....
```

which is not so nice. Therefore, the `Either` style is preferred for pure functions, and for IO/ST actions the other style is preferred.

For this, declare your native functions with a `throws ...` clause, as you have done already for `send` and `new`. The exception aware IO/ST action then looks like:

```
foo = do
          s <- Socket.new
          d <- s.send ....
          ...
   `catch` (\x1::SocketException -> ...)
   `catch` (\x2::IOException -> ....)
   ....
   `finally` finallyaction
```

There may be as many `catch`es as you need, but make sure to order them so that the most specific one comes before the less specific one, i.e. if ExceptionDerive extends ExceptionSuper, then the catch for ExceptionDerived must occur before the other one.
The `finally` clause is optional. Note that you don't have access to variables bound in the `do` block neither in the catch clauses nor in the finally clause. If you need this, you need to do the exception handling on a lower level (i.e., where some variable is bound to the value you need).

Please look up catch and finally in the frege doc or on Froogle.

Make sure the `catch` is indented *less* than the code in the *do* it guards. This is to make sure the compiler sees:

```
 do { .... } `catch` handler
```

You can as well write code without caring about exceptions, and add them only later. For example, you start with:

```
 action1 a b c = do 
       dothis a
       dothat b
       dosomethingelse c
       pure whatyouwant
```

Later, you can rename `action1` to `action1noex` and write

```
action1 a b c = action1noex a b c
      `catch`   ....
```

Second point. For data types that can only be used in the IO Monad, it is recommended to declare them as

```
data Socket = mutable native java......
```

This makes it possible to simply write `Socket` instead of `Mutable s Socket` or `Mutable RealWorld Socket`, since the compiler knows that such a value will always be mutable. You can use such types only in native functions that have a IO result.

Conversely, for data types that you just construct but never use in an impure way, you can define them as `pure native`.

I'm not sure about `InetSockAddress` but I guess it is not modified once constructed?

Likewise, rgd. the byte array. If you always and only ever want to convert this from and to strings, it can be treated as an utf8 text type (which we unfortunately don't have yet in the library). This would look like

```
data Charset = pure native java.nio.charset.Charset
pure native utf8 "java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8" :: Charset
data Bytes = pure native "byte[]" 
pure native getBytes :: String -> Charset -> Bytes
pure native getString new :: Bytes -> Charset -> String
toBytes s = getBytes s utf8
fromBytes bs = getString bs utf8
```

(untested, please ignore the warning concerning `byte[]` for now)

Comment: First point is clear to me, I hope. Ad 2, I tried to change ```data StringAsBytes = pure native java.lang.String where pure native getBytes :: String -> JArray Byte``` but I go ```Non pure native type JArray Byte must be ArrayOf s Byte in  ST actions.``` afterwards.

Comment: @libnull-dev That definition you're citing is needless (why redefine String?), it doesn't change the fact that *JArray* is a mutable type and so the compiler insists that it appears as `(Mutable s (Jarray Byte)` in ST/IO actions. It doesn't matter how you created the actual JArray.

Comment: Thanks, concerning `getBytes`  it was actually another question how to  avoid redefining native types to extend their functionality in Frege.

Comment: Look at the examples above, @libnull-dev : You just write the native function definition. In case you think that native functions must somehow be written in the where block following the data definition, no, this is not so, and it is nowhere said nor written that this would be so. However, only functions (no matter whether native or not) in the data (or instance) where block enjoy the `x.f` notation. Thus, if you really , really need this, you can write a type class and an instance for your type.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: you can wrap result of function (method) throwing exception into `Either`, like this: `native fn :: A -> Either SomeException B` or sugared version: `native fn :: (SomeException | B)`.

Secondly: Frege values are immutable. If you have got some data type A defined in Frege it is immutable. You are allowed to wrap some Java types and for immutable you mark them `pure`: `data D = pure native com.acme.D`. `InetSocketAddress` is not declared `pure`. This means that `ImmutableSocketAddress` can be changed by some other thread anywhere in time(for example closing socket). So Frege compiler marks it as `Mutable`. You can pass such data to Java functions only wrapped with `Mutable` taint.
You can write a function in Frege that doesn't need `Mutable` taint, but to pass it an argument you need to use some `readonly` or `Freezable` to get rid of `Mutable`.

Comment: Could you be more specific? This signature: `native new :: () -> ST s (SocketException | (Mutable s DatagramSocket))` is giving me `UDPTest.fr:38: can't find a type for  socket.send 'send' is neither an overloaded function nor a member of  (SocketException | Mutable RealWorld DatagramSocket)`.

Comment: OK, I changed `socket <- DatagramSocket.new ()` for `Right socket <- DatagramSocket.new ()` and it works, but what will happen in a case of `Left`?